# Accessing a variable that is initialized/declared in the constructor within a method belonging to the same class java

Tags: java, constructor

I need to use the variables from my constructor WinterCarnival() within my method update(). The update() method cannot have any parameters. I created an object of my FrozenStatue class in the constructor but I need to call a method from the FrozenStatue class from the update method. Essentially, I need to access frozStatObj01 within my update method.

public class WinterCarnival extends SimulationEngine {

```
public WinterCarnival() {
    ArrayList<FrozenStatue> objects = new ArrayList<FrozenStatue>(); 
    float[] fsObjPosition01 = new float[2];
        fsObjPosition01[0] = 600;
        fsObjPosition01[1] = 100;
    float[] fsObjPosition02 = new float[2];
        fsObjPosition02[0] = 200;
        fsObjPosition02[1] = 500;
    FrozenStatue frozStatObj01 = new FrozenStatue(fsObjPosition01);
    FrozenStatue frozStatObj02 = new FrozenStatue(fsObjPosition02);

    objects.add(frozStatObj01);
    objects.add(frozStatObj02);
} 

@Override
public void update() { 

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WinterCarnival wintCar = new WinterCarnival();
```

}
}

Comment: Hello Sarah, I see you have attached your code as an image. It would help get quality answers if you could inline the code (use the triple-backtick syntax for large blocks of code).

Comment: Here's an example of declaring and using member variables, also known as fields: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is the `objects` variable that you need to access from `update()`.

What you need to do is to move this from a local variable to a field, e.g.:

```
public class WinterCarnival {


...
    private ArrayList<FrozenStatue> objects;

    public WinterCarnival() {
        objects = new ArrayList<FrozenStatue>(); 
        float[] fsObjPosition01 = new float[2];
            fsObjPosition01[0] = 600;
            fsObjPosition01[1] = 100;
        float[] fsObjPosition02 = new float[2];
            fsObjPosition02[0] = 200;
            fsObjPosition02[1] = 500;
        FrozenStatue frozStatObj01 = new FrozenStatue(fsObjPosition01);
        FrozenStatue frozStatObj02 = new FrozenStatue(fsObjPosition02);

        objects.add(frozStatObj01);
        objects.add(frozStatObj02);
    } 

...

}
```

Now you can access `objects` from `update()`.

PS. You should generally avoid concrete types in variable declarations in favor of the interfaces. In your case, use `List` instead of `ArrayList`:

```
private List<FrozenStatue> objects;
```

You can still initialize it as an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Dovetalk gave you the correct answer, but let me add an explanation.

You were using LOCAL variables ...

- Local variables are declared in methods, constructors, or blocks.
- Local variables are created when the method, constructor or block is entered and the variable will be destroyed once it exits the method, constructor, or block.

To have 'scope' (to be visible) to other methods in your class, you needed to use an INSTANCE variable (MEMBER variable in some other languages.)

- Instance variables are declared in a class, but outside a method, constructor or any block.

This is what Dovetalk has done with your ArrayList object. Otherwise, it's only visible within the constructor, and is also destroyed once the constructor completes ... it was LOCAL only, just within the constructor. Dovetalk changed it to an INSTANCE variable. Then, it exists for the whole life of a WinterCarnival instance, and is visible to all the methods in the WinterCarnival class.

I hope that adds an explanation for you about what was going on there.